# How to sort value after using groupby and choose the most frequent one?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So Actually there are two question, first one is how I can get this sorted? I tried to add sort_value() following .mean() but it's not working.
[image: First Question]

The second question is I can use .mean() to get the average value for price after groupby. How I can get the most frequent one? For example I want to get 100 if 100 is the most frequent price in area Allson.

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: for ques.1, did u use `df.sort_values(by=['col'])` ?

Comment: for quest 2 `df['col'].mode()` will give the most frequent value for the column

Comment: `sort_values` should work. Can you show exactly how you're doing it and explain *why* it is not working? (e.g. returns an error?)

Answer (score 1):

For question 1, `df.groupby('neighourhood_cleansed').apply(pd.DataFrame.sort_values, 'price')`. After doing the group by, we are sorting on the group_by dataframe object so we use `apply` to say we do sort on the column price.

For question 2, try `df['col'].mode()`.

`df.groupby('...').apply(pd.DataFrame.mode, 'col_name')` will work after a groupby.

Comment: Hi Gimhani, thank you for the quick reply. For the first one, it shows `AttributeError: type object 'DataFrame' has no attribute 'sort'`. For the second one, what I want is the most frequent one after groupby, meaning I need the most frequent one in each group. df['col'].mode can give me the most frequent one in that column but I want the most frequent price( or other property) in each neighbourhood...Thank you ~

Comment: Problem 1 solved.....I used sort_value()...should use sort_values(). How about problem 2 any idea?

Comment: @ShihaoWen can't use use '.mode()' ? since mode means the most frequent

Comment: try `df.groupby('...').apply(pd.DataFrame.mode, 'col_name')`

Answer (score 0):

For question 1:

```
df.groupby('neighourhood_cleansed').apply(pd.DataFrame.sort_values, 'price')
```

`groupby`+`apply`+sorting for above

For question 2:

```
df['col'].mode()
```

`mode` for above